# Swap function that works for any types in C

Tags: c

I don't know if it's possible but I'm trying to do a `swap` function that swaps two variables and works for any type of variable as long as the two variables to swap are of the same type, what I did is using `void *` type:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void ft_swap(void **a, void **b)
{
    void    *tmp;

    tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = INT_MAX;
    unsigned long c = 10;
    unsigned long d = ULONG_MAX;

    printf("BEFORE\na = %d\nb = %d\nc = %zu\nd = %zu\n", a, b, c, d);
    ft_swap((void **)&a, (void **)&b);
    ft_swap((void **)&c, (void **)&d);
    printf("AFTER\na = %d\nb = %d\nc = %zu\nd = %zu\n", a, b, c, d);
    return (0);
}
```

The output is:

```
BEFORE
a = 5
b = 2147483647
c = 10
d = 18446744073709551615
AFTER
a = 0
b = 5
c = 18446744073709551615
d = 10
```

I know that `void *` type is the same size as unsigned long, but can someone explain my what's wrong with the `int` variables, for me it should work as `int` is a smaller type? the `5` got swapped, but `INT_MAX` became `0`, what happened here?

EDIT: I did a version as you told me: using long long pointer but it also doesn't work, it changes the value of the int.

Comment: If `void *` is larger than `int` on your system, e.g. most 64-bit systems where it's 8 bytes versus 4, you just overwrote 4 bytes of whatever happened to be in memory following `a` and `b`.  If they're adjacent then one of these may have overwritten the other.

Comment: Instead of `void *` I would use `unsigned long long *`. But no matter, hwat, as long as you don't pass sizeinfo this function will invoke undefined behaviour mostly.

Comment: Actually, `sizeof(void *)` doesn't have to be the same as `sizeof(unsigned long)`. Try doing it on a 64-bit Windows system using the MSVC compiler and it will break down. In fact, as you noted, it will break down in any case where the actual types are different from `sizeof(void *)`.

Comment: If you want a generic *integer* type that can fit all kinds of integers *and* pointers, use e.g. `uintptr_t` instead. But to solve your problem "properly", I recommend you do some research about [*generic selection*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) instead.

Comment: It seems like you have some confusion about what `void *` can do.  It can safely be used to *point* to any type.  That doesn't mean you can safely *use* any type *as if it were* `void *`, which seems to be what you're trying to do here.

Comment: The `(void **)` casts used to bludgeon the compiler into accepting your code are a strong indication of problems.

Comment: The thing you're trying to do _can be done_; the implementation of `qsort` does it.  However, this is not how you do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your swap function makes no sense at all (I can't even guess what is the idea behind it).

Your function has to know references to the objects and their size. Then it needs to copy the memory occupied by them.

Here you have the more correct one:

```
void swap(void *d1, void *d2, size_t size)
{
    unsigned char temp[size];

    memcpy(temp, d1, size);
    memcpy(d1, d2, size);
    memcpy(d2, temp, size);
}

struct st
{
    int a;
    double b;
    char c[10];
};

int main(void)
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = INT_MAX;
    unsigned long c = 10;
    unsigned long d = ULONG_MAX;
    struct st x = {1,2.0, "text1"};
    struct st y = {5,20.0, "text2"};


    printf("BEFORE\na = %d\nb = %d\nc = %zu\nd = %zu\n", a, b, c, d);
    swap(&a, &b, sizeof(a));
    swap(&c, &d, sizeof(c));
    printf("AFTER\na = %d\nb = %d\nc = %zu\nd = %zu\n", a, b, c, d);
    printf("struct before: %d %f %s, %d %f %s\n", x.a, x.b, x.c, y.a, y.b, y.c);
    swap(&x, &y, sizeof(x));
    printf("struct after: %d %f %s, %d %f %s\n", x.a, x.b, x.c, y.a, y.b, y.c);
    return (0);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/er95YYjca